# Throwing exception after modifying its Dictionary

Tags: c#, exception, throw, catch-block, rethrow

The following is my code in C#:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.Data.Add("VarName", "object");
   throw;
}
```

Question: doing above, am I going to lose the entry I am adding to Data dictionary? -->as in my opinion, I am rethrowing the exception caught in the catch statement, and it does not have the added Dictionary record from the next line yet.

Should above code instead be:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.Data.Add("VarName", "object");
   throw ex;
}
```

- but in this case, I don't want to reset the stack trace.

Searched this all over the web and on SO, but no luck.

TIA!

Comment: If you want to add some data to exception, then wrap exception in more specific exception with data, and throw that specific exception

Comment: Have you tried it; it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to write some sample code that tests?

Comment: just tried - Bart's answer is correct. My initial code works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial code should work just fine. You should not lose the dictionary entry.

**[EDIT]**: Elaboration.

Let's take the following example code:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Change();
        Replace();
        Inner();
    }

    static void Change()
    {
        try {
            try {
                throw new Exception("This is a message");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.Data.Add("foo", "bar");
                throw;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Data["foo"]);
        }
    }

    static void Replace()
    {
        try {
            try {
                throw new Exception("This is a message");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e = new Exception("Different message", e);
                e.Data.Add("foo", "bar");
                throw;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Data["foo"]);
        }
    }

    static void Inner()
    {
        try {
            try {
                throw new Exception("This is a message");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.Data.Add("foo1", "bar1");
                e = new Exception("Different message", e);
                e.Data.Add("foo2", "bar2");
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Data["foo2"]);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Data["foo1"]);
        }
    }
}
```

When throwing an `Exception`, what is really thrown is a reference to an Exception object. That reference is what is caught and rethrown. Modifying the underlying object is fine. This is what your initial code does, and what the `Change` method in my example does.

In the `Replace` method we modify not the object, but the reference itself. We make it point to a brand new `Exception` object with a different message and to top it off we also add some data. All this stuff is lost, though, because `throw` without arguments rethrows the original reference.

Should the need arise to use the second case, you can keep track of your stack trace by including the original exception as `InnerException`, like I did in the `Inner` method.